# Docker MySQL не работает

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Только начала пользоваться Docker. Не могу понять почему не работает MySQL. Очень нужна помощь.

файл .yml

```
version: '2'
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "344:344"
        volumes:
            - ./hosts:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - ./www:/var/www
            - ./logs:/var/log/nginx
        links:
            - php
    php:
        build: ./images/php
        links:
            - mysql
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www
    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./init.sql:/mysql/init.sql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: polinanov_avito
            MYSQL_DATABASE: polinanov_avito
            MYSQL_USER: polinanov_avito
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: polinanov_avito
        networks:
            - wp-net
networks:
    wp-net:
        driver: bridge
```

Функция подключения к базе данных

```
$link = mysqli_connect( 
        'mysql',
        'polinanov_avito',     
        'polinanov_avito',  
        'polinanov_avito');
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm

MAINTAINER Polina <ms.polinanov@mail.ru>
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y\
        curl \
        wget \
        git \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt mbstring mysqli pdo_mysql zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

ADD php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/40-custom.ini

WORKDIR /var/www

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Ошибки при попытке вызова функции:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in <b>/var/www/hello.dev/classApi.php</b> on line <b>93</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in <b>/var/www/hello.dev/classApi.php</b> on line <b>93</b><br />
"Internal Error BD"
```

Answer (score 1):

> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in ...

Backend не может подключиться к `mysql`.

> ```
> php:
>   links:
>     - mysql
> mysql:
>   networks:
>     - wp-net
> ```

Почему? Не связаны одной сетью. Советую использовать api версии не старее 3.0.

```
version: 3.0
services:
  php:
    networks:
      - net
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=mysql.example_net
      - MYSQL_PORT=3306
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: polinanov_avito
      - MYSQL_DATABASE: polinanov_avito
      - MYSQL_USER: polinanov_avito
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD: polinanov_avito 
  mysql:
    networks:
      - net
networks:
  - net # bridge by default
```

**Почему версию 3.0?**

В ней для связи ипользуются dns нотация.
К примеру для `mysql` - `mysql.project_path_net:3306`. Можно менять название проекта через env переменную `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=test` в `.env` файле -> `mysql.test_net:3306`.

**Для коннекта к базе используем переменные окружения**, а не харкодим их.